# cordova-icon does nothing after saying "Generating Icons for"

Tags: android, ios, cordova, npm

I am using [cordova-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-icon) for generating my icons for my Cordova app.

However, instead of actually generating the icons as it has done in the past, it simply halts with no errors and having done nothing after this output :

```
 Checking Project & Icon

  ✓  platforms found: ios, android
  ✓  icon.png exists
  ✓  config.xml exists

 Generating Icons for ios
```

Why is `cordova-icon` not generating my icons?
(for either Android or iOS)

Answer (score 1):

**I resolved this by re-installing imagicmagick.**

On my mac I simply did :

`$ brew upgrade imagemagick`

And the next time `cordova-icon` ran successfully.